# Expansion of Arabluatex macro does not work

Tags: luatex, arabic

I work with ArabLuatex on the edition of a scholarly Arabic text.

In my Arabic text I want to differentiate between fully vocalized fragments in text blocks that are sparingly vocalized. I wish to mark these fragments with another color.

When I put the instructions, starting with `\RL`, directly in the text, the fragment is correctly colored and vocalized.

Yet when I put the code in a macro, the fragment is colored, but the `voc` or `fullvoc` instruction does not work.

Has anybody a solution?

A minimal example (to be processed with lualatex) follows underneath.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.35]{Scheherazade}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Gentium Book Basic}

%\newcommand*{\trk}[1]{\LR{\textcolor{red}{1 #1} \arb[fullvoc]{2 #1}}}
%\newcommand{\trk}[1]{{{\color{red}{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand*{\trk}[1]{\LR{\textcolor{red}{\arb[fullvoc]{#1}}}}
%\newcommand*{\trk}[1]{\LR{\textcolor{red}{\arb[fullvoc]{#1}}}}
%\long\gdef\trk#1{\textcolor{red}{\arb[fullvoc]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{arab}[novoc]

'a_hAfu mina 'l-malik-i 'lla_dI ya.zlimu 'l-nAs-a 

\RL{\textcolor{green}{\arb[fullvoc]{'a_hAfu mina 'l-malik-i 'lla_dI ya.zlimu 'l-nAs-a}}}

\trk{'a_hAfu mina 'l-malik-i 'lla_dI ya.zlimu 'l-nAs-a}

\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is not related to TeX expansion mechanism, nor it is to the color commands.  Actually `arabluatex` expects any single-argument command to have Arabic text in its argument: see the general principle that is laid in sect. 10 on p. 37 of the documentation for more information.

For example, if you try to create this simple command: `\newcommand{\fvarabic}[1]{\arb[fullvoc]{#1}}`, then use it inside a, say, `novoc` environment, it will always produce non-vocalized Arabic because its argument will have been processed by the `novoc` rules before `\fvarabic` can see it.

I would argue this is more a feature than an actual bug ;)

For the time being, as a workaround, you may prefix any new command that you would like to create by `\RL` for it to be accepted by `arabluatex` as one that does not have only running Arabic text in its argument, like so:

```
\newcommand{\RLtrk}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\arb[fullvoc]{#1}}}
```

This will work.

The next release of `arabluatex` (to be published in a couple of days) will allow to "declare" such new commands so that `arabluatex` will handle them just as `\RL`, `\LR` and the like.

---

**EDIT** [arabluatex 1.9 is out](http://git.robertalessi.net/arabluatex) and should be available on the mirrors of CTAN in a couple of days.  A new command `\MkArbBreak` which allows to ˘declare° new commands to be inserted in Arabic environments has been added (see 10.1 p. 39 in the documentation of v1.9).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Ulrike's response does not work. The vocalisation does not show in the red text.

I found the following solution:

```
\newcommand{\trk}[1]{\RL{\textcolor{red}{\arb[fullvoc]{#1}}}}

\begin{luacode}
function trk_help ( s )
 s = string.gsub ( s , "\\trk%b{}"   ,   "\\RL{%0}" )
 return s
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", trk_help , "trk_help" )
\end{luacode}
```

Yet I do not why it works.

Comment: You are right,my solution  it doesn't work. I looked only at the begin and not at the rest of the text. The arab environment looks (with lua) for the string `\arb` and handles this in a special way. So it looks as if the only "pure latex" solution would be to redefine/patch \arb to add colors.

Comment: Quite right.  Actual support for colors has not been added yet in arabluatex, hence the `\LR` advice.  I'll add some basic support in a couple of days.